# Error:(249, 22) error: cannot find symbol variable cerrar

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo el siguiente problema. estoy agregando un menú para mi aplicación pero me sale el siguiente error.

```
Error:(249, 22) error: cannot find symbol variable cerrar
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_refresh:

                loadDashboard();
                añadirProgress();
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11/*HONEYCOMB*/) {
                   new  AsyncTask_load().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                } else {
                    new AsyncTask_load().execute();
                }
                return true;

            case R.id.cerrar:

                logOut();

                return true;

            case  R.id.action_notification:

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NotificationActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);

                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

Mi menú el el siguiente.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_notification"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_notifications"
        android:title="notification"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/cerrar"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_https_green_500_24dp"
        android:title="cerrar"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_refresh_green_a700_24dp"
    android:title="@string/refresh"
    app:showAsAction="always" />


</menu>
```

Lo curioso es que solo me sale error con el Id cerrar y no en los otros. Cuando borro en java la llamada al Id Cerrar compila normal. Pero cuando lo agrego me bota el error ya mencionada.

Agradecería su ayuda.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: realiza lo que comento en mi respuesta, posiblemente tienes otro error que impide crear los ids de recursos dentro de R.java

Comment: si funcionó mucha gracias... :)

Answer (score 1):

Si tienes definido el elemento en los recursos (layout) y no puede resolver el id, puede ser que exista un problema en alguna otra parte de tu proyecto que impida agregar ese id al archivo `R.java` o simplemente requieras "limpiar" tu proyecto, .

Realiza la limpieza de tu proyecto y vuelvelo a construir:

`Build` > `Clean Project`

y posteriormente:

`Build` > `Rebuild Project`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Genial!!!!! muchas gracias amigo me salvaste... :)

Comment: Excelene David, son pequeños detalles que con experiencia se aprenden, saludos.